# Destroy flash object using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash

I have a flash object that connects to the user's webcam.

In Firefox, I can remove the container div of the object (using jQuery) and the camera will turn off.
However, in IE8, when I remove the container div, the camera stays on but the flash object appears to be removed from the DOM.

Is there a way to sever the connection between IE and the webcam so the light on the webcam will go off when the flash object is removed from the DOM?

Comment: Are you the author of the swf? Can you modify its code?

Comment: If you embed with the SWFObject library it has a function removeSWF() that is crossbrowser capable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it looks like I was just being impatient!  IE eventually releases the connection to the webcam (and turns off the light), it just takes about 15 seconds.  I assume this is just a difference in how the garbage collectors work.

Comment: Glad you figured it out. IE isn't great at times.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried emptying the div opposed to disposing of it? Perhaps IE just hides the div where as fire fox empties it, then hides it.

Comment: I'll give that a go now and report back shortly

Comment: Unfortunately it has the same effect.